# A* pathfinding to moving targets with queue's

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding, a-star

I have been following some guides and have put together a pathfinder using the A* algorithm. The code queue's units into a pathfinding queue and moves the units towards the target. This works fine but it only takes the position of the target on initialization, and if I move around the units only walk towards that initial position and stop.

What I want is for them to be able to follow around the player as they move and choose the best path towards the player like any zombie game would.

I have thought of a few ways to do this but I am not sure how the processing power would react when there are hundreds of zombies. I could dequeue all of the pathfinding units every time the target moves and reinitialize their movement, but I don't know how well this would work.

If someone could give me a good approach to this that would be great. Theres quite a lot of code here but I will provide it anyways as a reference to what I am doing.

PathRequestManager.cs:

```
public class PathRequestManager : MonoBehaviour {

Queue<PathRequest> pathRequestQueue = new Queue<PathRequest>();
PathRequest currentPathRequest;

static PathRequestManager instance;
Pathfinding pathfinding;

bool isProcessingPath;

void Awake() {
    instance = this;
    pathfinding = GetComponent<Pathfinding>();
}

public static void RequestPath(Vector3 pathStart, Vector3 pathEnd, Action<Vector3[], bool> callback) {
    PathRequest newRequest = new PathRequest(pathStart,pathEnd,callback);
    instance.pathRequestQueue.Enqueue(newRequest);
    instance.TryProcessNext();
}

void TryProcessNext() {
    if (!isProcessingPath && pathRequestQueue.Count > 0) {
        currentPathRequest = pathRequestQueue.Dequeue();
        isProcessingPath = true;
        pathfinding.StartFindPath(currentPathRequest.pathStart, currentPathRequest.pathEnd);
    }
}

public void FinishedProcessingPath(Vector3[] path, bool success) {
    currentPathRequest.callback(path,success);
    isProcessingPath = false;
    TryProcessNext();
}

struct PathRequest {
    public Vector3 pathStart;
    public Vector3 pathEnd;
    public Action<Vector3[], bool> callback;

    public PathRequest(Vector3 _start, Vector3 _end, Action<Vector3[], bool> _callback) {
        pathStart = _start;
        pathEnd = _end;
        callback = _callback;
    }

}
```

PathFinding.cs:

```
public class Pathfinding : MonoBehaviour {


PathRequestManager requestManager;
Grid grid;

void Awake() {
    requestManager = GetComponent<PathRequestManager>();
    grid = GetComponent<Grid>();
}


public void StartFindPath(Vector3 startPos, Vector3 targetPos) {
    StartCoroutine(FindPath(startPos,targetPos));
}

IEnumerator FindPath(Vector3 startPos, Vector3 targetPos) {

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    Vector3[] waypoints = new Vector3[0];
    bool pathSuccess = false;

    Node startNode = grid.NodeFromWorldPoint(startPos);
    Node targetNode = grid.NodeFromWorldPoint(targetPos);

    if (startNode.walkable && targetNode.walkable) {
        Heap<Node> openSet = new Heap<Node>(grid.MaxSize);
        HashSet<Node> closedSet = new HashSet<Node>();
        openSet.Add(startNode);

        while (openSet.Count > 0) {
            Node currentNode = openSet.RemoveFirst();
            closedSet.Add(currentNode);

            if (currentNode == targetNode) {
                sw.Stop();
                print ("Path found: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
                pathSuccess = true;
                break;
            }

            foreach (Node neighbour in grid.GetNeighbours(currentNode)) {
                if (!neighbour.walkable || closedSet.Contains(neighbour)) {
                    continue;
                }

                int newMovementCostToNeighbour = currentNode.gCost + GetDistance(currentNode, neighbour);
                if (newMovementCostToNeighbour < neighbour.gCost || !openSet.Contains(neighbour)) {
                    neighbour.gCost = newMovementCostToNeighbour;
                    neighbour.hCost = GetDistance(neighbour, targetNode);
                    neighbour.parent = currentNode;

                    if (!openSet.Contains(neighbour))
                        openSet.Add(neighbour);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    yield return null;
    if (pathSuccess) {
        waypoints = RetracePath(startNode,targetNode);
    }
    requestManager.FinishedProcessingPath(waypoints,pathSuccess);

}

Vector3[] RetracePath(Node startNode, Node endNode) {
    List<Node> path = new List<Node>();
    Node currentNode = endNode;

    while (currentNode != startNode) {
        path.Add(currentNode);
        currentNode = currentNode.parent;
    }
    Vector3[] waypoints = SimplifyPath(path);
    Array.Reverse(waypoints);
    return waypoints;

}

Vector3[] SimplifyPath(List<Node> path) {
    List<Vector3> waypoints = new List<Vector3>();
    Vector2 directionOld = Vector2.zero;

    for (int i = 1; i < path.Count; i ++) {
        Vector2 directionNew = new Vector2(path[i-1].gridX - path[i].gridX,path[i-1].gridY - path[i].gridY);
        if (directionNew != directionOld) {
            waypoints.Add(path[i].worldPosition);
        }
        directionOld = directionNew;
    }
    return waypoints.ToArray();
}

int GetDistance(Node nodeA, Node nodeB) {
    int dstX = Mathf.Abs(nodeA.gridX - nodeB.gridX);
    int dstY = Mathf.Abs(nodeA.gridY - nodeB.gridY);

    if (dstX > dstY)
        return 14*dstY + 10* (dstX-dstY);
    return 14*dstX + 10 * (dstY-dstX);
}


}
```

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions when you use them, "Unity" is for the Microsoft Unity Framework (not Unity3D), Path is for file paths. It'll help categorize your question and get the right people to look at it. Also no need to put the tags in your title.

Comment: It wouldn't let me use pathfinding cuz I don't have high enough reputation, and didn't know that about unity. Thanks though